# I need a query that can output 1 row per column while summing the contents of that column and grouping by another column (chart inside to simplify)

Tags: sql, sql-server, sqlite, pivot

I have a database that contains phone call records (I am NOT a telemarketer, this is emergency call data).  Each row is a call record.  Some of the columns contain timing information.  There is also a priority column for each call.  It looks like this:

```
  PRIORITY    TIMING1     TIMING2     TIMING3
  -----0----------22----------3-----------43 
  -----1----------42----------10----------12
  -----0----------12----------13----------6
  -----2----------23----------12----------37
  -----1----------12----------16----------23
```

The output that I need is basically this one row per timing with the sum of all the time grouped by priority as columns.  There are a fixed number of timings and priorities that I know of ahead of time.  It would look like this:

```
------------Priority 0-------Priority 1-------Priority 2
  Timing1----123--------------332--------------233
  Timing2----265--------------241--------------302
  Timing3----387--------------192--------------201
```

Is it possible to do something like this in a single query?  The query also has to be runnable on a mobile platform that is fairly resource constrained, although time to run isn't a huge deal.  Given the size of this table and the memory issue I would rather avoid temporary tables.

Comment: Could you flip the table - have Priority 0, 1, 2 as the rows and Timing 1, 2, 3 as columns?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `UNPIVOT` and `PIVOT` for this:

Here is a Static Version of the query - a static version means that you hard-code the values.

```
select *
from
(
  select *
  from
  (
    select priority, timing1, timing2, timing3
    from yourtable
  ) x
  unpivot
  (
    value
    for field in (timing1, timing2, timing3)
  ) u
) x1
pivot
(
  sum(value)
  for priority in ([0], [1], [2])
) p
```

## see [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ae19b/1)

You can also do this Dynamically:

```
DECLARE @colsUnpivot AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @colsPivot as  NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @colsPivotName as  NVARCHAR(MAX)

select @colsUnpivot = stuff((select ','+ quotename(C.name)
         from sys.columns as C
         where C.object_id = object_id('yourtable') and
               C.name LIKE 'timing%'
         for xml path('')), 1, 1, '')

select @colsPivot = 
    STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + Quotename(priority)
             from yourtable
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

select @colsPivotName = 
    STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' 
           + Quotename(priority) + ' as Priority' + cast(priority as varchar(1))
             from yourtable
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

set @query 
  = 'select col, '+ @colsPivotName +'
      from
      (
        select priority, val, col
        from 
        (
          select priority, ' + @colsUnpivot + '
          from yourtable
        ) x
        unpivot
        (
          val
          for col in ('+ @colsUnpivot +')
        ) u
      ) x1
      pivot
      (
        sum(val)
        for priority in ( '+ @colspivot + ')
      ) p'

exec(@query)
```

## see [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ae19b/30)

Edit #1, you stated in the comments that you are using SQLite which does not have a `PIVOT` function. But you can still do this using a `UNION ALL` and then an aggregate function with a `CASE`:

```
select col,
  sum(case when priority = 0 then value end) as Priority0,
  sum(case when priority = 1 then value end) as Priority1,
  sum(case when priority = 2 then value end) as Priority2
from
(
  select priority, timing1 as value, 'timing1' as col
  from yourtable
  union all
  select priority, timing2 as value, 'timing2' as col
  from yourtable
  union all
  select priority, timing3 as value, 'timing3' as col
  from yourtable
) x
group by col
```

## see [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/102af/4)

Comment: @BurntToast see my edit, I added a dynamic version in the even you have many priority numbers that need to be transformed.

Comment: Thanks!  That's beautiful.  Sadly I've just learned I'll have to run this on a SQLite data base too which doesn't support Pivot.  =(

Comment: @BurntToast please see my edit, I wrote it using a `UNION ALL` with an aggregate and `CASE` statement, it will produce the same results.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind flipping/inverting the table, you could try this:

```
SELECT PRIORITY, SUM(TIMING1), SUM(TIMING2), SUM(TIMING3)
  FROM tbl
 GROUP BY PRIORITY
 ORDER BY PRIORITY
```

Comment: Sadly that isn't an option.  Thanks though!

Answer (score 0):

Use the SQL Sum and Over functions to perform an aggregate summation, see this link: http://www.sqlteam.com/article/sql-sever-2005-using-over-with-aggregate-functions

Answer (score 0):

Since you say there are a fixed number of rows and columns you know about, here is the naive implementation:

```
SELECT 'Timing1' AS Timing, SUM(IIF(PRIORITY = 0, TIMING1, 0)) AS [Priority 0],
    SUM(IIF(PRIORITY = 1, TIMING1, 0)) AS [Priority 1], 
    SUM(IIF(PRIORITY = 2, TIMING1, 0)) AS [Priority 2]
FROM CallRecords
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Timing2' AS Timing, SUM(IIF(PRIORITY = 0, TIMING2, 0)) AS [Priority 0], 
    SUM(IIF(PRIORITY = 1, TIMING2, 0)) AS [Priority 1], 
    SUM(IIF(PRIORITY = 2, TIMING2, 0)) AS [Priority 2]
FROM CallRecords
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Timing3' AS Timing, SUM(IIF(PRIORITY = 0, TIMING3, 0)) AS [Priority 0], 
    SUM(IIF(PRIORITY = 1, TIMING3, 0)) AS [Priority 1], 
    SUM(IIF(PRIORITY = 2, TIMING3, 0)) AS [Priority 2]
FROM CallRecords
```

It is probably faster, though to flip the table as @n8wrl suggests, unless you absolutely need it in this format.